# ActiveRecord where similar to find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Rails have method where which returns Relation and find method which accepts entity and looks based on primary (you shouldn't specify it explicit).

Is there any where method which accepts entity?

eg, `User.where(params[:id])` -> select .. from users where user.id = ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the user record, why do you need to find it again using where? If it's an association, you can do something like `User.where(:company_id => company.id)`, but you can't pass the record itself.

Also,`User.find(params[:id])` is the same as `User.where(:id => params[:id]).first`.

Comment: I meant this: Post.find(params[:id]) - will use id and look Post.primary_key == id, how can i do this using where method?

Comment: id specified explicitly. find(params[:id]) uses primary key from mapping. Find will work with FriendlyId, but where wont.

Comment: Why is your primary key something other than id? Rails doesn't like that. I'd recommend changing that back if you can to avoid tearing out your hair. See also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079195/how-to-set-primary-key-in-ruby-on-rails-migration

Comment: I wanted https://github.com/norman/friendly_id to play with where. I thought the point is to change primary key, but i was mistaken, FriendlyId overrides finder methods. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

The following works, but I don't understand why you are looking for an object you already have?

```
User.where(:id => user)
```

Comment: id specified explicitly. find(params[:id]) uses primary key from mapping

Comment: Can you please say more about the context, where you need this?

Comment: I figure out, friendly id overrides finder methods. I was mistaken. Anyway, thanks for help!