# Setting user id in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a webapp that gives an option to create a new user. However, the problem is that `idUser` is null I have to generate it automatically.

How do I set `:idUser`? I have an idea of using `User.last.id+1` but I have troubles implementing it.

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :surname, :email, :password, :userName, :idUser)
end
```

Comment: The `id` should be generated automatically!

Comment: rails (and more generally ruby) doesn't use camelCase, the convention is snake_case, you don't need `idUser`, `id` is a column automatically provided by rails (except you have monkeyed things) and it is by default auto-incrementing

Comment: It unfortently is not since I generated models from  db and not the other way around. So I am stuck with idUsers that doesnt automaticly generate.

Comment: How is the `users` table defined inside the existing database? How were the `idUser` values assigned to the existing rows? BTW, `User.last.id+1` is not a good approach, that's subject to race conditions and can produce bad values if rows are deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Add the primary key in your class definition

`class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "idUser"
end`

and then the params should be handled correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

User.rb

```
before_create :generate_reference

private

def generate_id
  self.reference = loop do
    token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)[0..19]
    break token unless Request.exists?(reference: token)
    self.idUser = token
  end
end
```

Comment: this is prone to race conditions, all this work should be done by the DB and not in your code

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is pretty lame, but nonetheless you'll want to do one of the following:

1. Set the "primary key" as `idUser`
2. Pull the `idUser` and "increment" it manually
3. Use `UUID` functionality

---

1 - In your DB, you can set your `primary_key` to `idUser`, which *should* allow you to provide auto-increment functionality:

```
$ rails g migration AddPrimaryKey

# db/migrate/add_primary_key______.rb
class AddPrimaryKey < ActiveRecord::Migration

   def self.up
      execute "ALTER TABLE users modify `idUser` id int(8) AUTO_INCREMENT"
      execute "ALTER TABLE users ADD PRIMARY KEY (idUser);"
   end

   def self.down
      execute "ALTER TABLE users modify `idUser` id int(8)"
   end

end

$ rake db:migrate
```

Some wise advice from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10079409/1143732):

> Use the built-in `id` field as the primary key. If you're going to use Rails, you should build your app the "Rails way" unless you have very good reason not to.

--

2 - You could use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17523916/1143732):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create :set_id, if: "idUser.blank?"

   private

   def set_id
      self[:idUser] = User.maximum(:idUser).next
   end
end
```

--

3 - If you wanted to use the inbuilt [`uuid` functionality](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#uuid) of Rails, you'd be able to set the `idUser` as the primary key (above), but instead of making it auto-increment, make it a string and add a `UUID` generator to it:

```
# db/migrate/add_primary_key______.rb
class AddPrimaryKey < ActiveRecord::Migration

   def self.up
      execute "ALTER TABLE users ADD PRIMARY KEY (idUser);"
      if Rails.env.staging? #-> Heroku PGSQL
          execute("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS \"uuid-ossp\"")
      else #-> MYSQL
          execute("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS before_insert_users;");
          execute("CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_nodes BEFORE INSERT ON users FOR EACH ROW SET new.uuid = uuid();")
      end
   end

end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   set_primary_key "idUser"
end
```

This will allow you to just use rails as if you were using an `id` / `uuid` column, `ActiveRecord` referencing `idUser` as required.