# Rails: How to set value to "id" column which is not primary key

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to manually set value to field "ID" in my table which is not a primary key. Everytime I use the .id attribute and assign value to it, it gets assigned to the primary key (abc_id) but not "id"

```
table/model: MyModel
primary key: abc_id
another column: id
```

i tried following ways of saving an ID but none of them seemed to work.

```
test = MyModel.new
test.id = 555 
==> updates abc_id
test.write_attribute(:id, 555)
 ==> private method not available
test.update_attribute(:id,555)
==> updates abc_id -->ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
test.attributes = {id: 555} 
==> no error but doesn't do anything
test.send(:attributes=, id: 555) 
==> saves other attributes but not id
 => nil
```

How can I assign value to "id" since I always get `PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint` error while trying to save the record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this answer help?

[How to set primary key in ruby on rails migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079195/how-to-set-primary-key-in-ruby-on-rails-migration)

In my experience this shouldn't be necessary though.